# Plugin log level in OpenDistro cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I have a fresh opendistro cluster that works fine, but I try to disable some traces in log and there is one that I can't remove.

The lines of log look like this :

```
[2020-04-22T10:09:17,502][INFO ][stats_log                ] [myhost01] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Program=PerformanceAnalyzerPlugin
StartTime=1580542897.428
EndTime=Wed, 21 Apr 2020 10:09:17 CEST
Time=60074 msecs
Timing=total-time:60074.0/1
Counters=TotalError=0
EOE
```

It's clearly written by the PerformanceAnalyzer Plugin provided by opendistro, so I try to change the log config/log4j2.properties of this plugin and I've restarted the master (myhost01 in this example) but no change in log.

My question is : How to change the log level of this plugin?

Comment: What are the changes that you tried?

Comment: I change the verbosity on the log4j2.properties file at /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_performance_analyzer/config and I've totally restarted the cluster after that

Comment: I've raised a bug about this on github repo : https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/performance-analyzer/issues/98#issuecomment-696019717. At the moment is not fixed  (v1.9.0)